# Group query Items despite diferent values on group by expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to find a way to group items from a table based on 3 columns as follows

**INITAL TABLE:**

```
_id | ind_cel_phone | ind_home_phone
------------------------------------
1   |    TRUE       |     FALSE
1   |    FALSE      |     FALSE
2   |    TRUE       |     FALSE
3   |    TRUE       |     FALSE
4   |    TRUE       |     FALSE
2   |    FALSE      |     FALSE
5   |    TRUE       |     TRUE
6   |    TRUE       |     TRUE
1   |    FALSE      |     TRUE
```

The result I'm expecting is somthing like:

```
_id | ind_cel_phone | ind_home_phone
------------------------------------
1   |    TRUE       |     TRUE
2   |    TRUE       |     FALSE
3   |    TRUE       |     FALSE
4   |    TRUE       |     FALSE
5   |    TRUE       |     TRUE
6   |    TRUE       |     TRUE
```

**Notice:**

- _id = 1 got three rows the first TRUE-FALSE, the second FALSE-FALSE, the third FALSE-TRUE and the result  is TRUE-TRUE
- _id = 2 got two rows the first TRUE-FALSE, the second FALSE-FALSE and the result is TRUE-FALSE

Where if there are two or more rows of the same _id but their ind_* columns have different values the TRUE value got a priority.

I tried something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    _id
,   ind_cel_phone
,   ind_home_phone
FROM base_table
GROUP BY _id
    ,   ind_cel_phone
    ,   ind_home_phone
```

Since values are different my result table is the same as the inital one and not as the expected result.

Is there a way I can group them in order to get the expected result?

Comment: Step 1: Do GROUP BY _id, since you want one row per _id as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) should do it:

```
select _id, bool_or(ind_cel_phone), bool_or(ind_home_phone)
from base_table
group by _id
```

Comment: Why not use `MAX()` instead? The ANSI/ISO SQL way, and should be portable.

Comment: @jarlh . . . I get this error in Postgres:  "ERROR:  function max(boolean) does not exist".  To be honest, I am also inclined to write this as `count(*) filter (where bool_col) > 0`, but `bool_or()` and `bool_and()` is really more convenient.